# Show injective/ surjective for fraction function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, discrete-mathematics

I was asked to show whether $$f: [0, +\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ defined by $$  f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x}+3}{x-4}$$ is injective or surjective. My proof involves setting $f(x) = t$ and show $t(x-4) = \sqrt{x} +3$ has unique solution. However, I'm not sure if multiplication by $x-4$ is permissible, given that $f(4)$ is not defined in the real. Any suggestions is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain of the function given can not be right, as it is not defined at $x=4$ as you saw. Assuming the function is defined from $\mathbb{R^+} \setminus \{4\} \to \mathbb{R}$, you can continue your argument by assuming $0 \leq x \neq 4$, thus multiplying by $(x-4)$ is legal. Remember to only include positive solutions when determining $x$ and that raising the equation to the second power can give you more solutions. Remember to check both solutions when done.